# Restore Version of Node in Mesh-UI

Tags: gentics-mesh

Where can we restore old node versions in the Mesh-UI and on the REST level? 
As I can see each time I update a Node we get a new Version.

But how can we access old version and restore them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restoring versions is not directly possible but you can load older versions using the `version` parameter: https://demo.getmesh.io/api/v1/demo/nodes/079ae5d5467447b99ae5d5467447b934?version=1.1 and update the node using this data.

We plan to add full version restore in future versions of the new Gentics Mesh UI.